# Moving "last name" from last to first in Attribute Table of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-9.3

How do you get *e.g.* "John D. Doe" to "Doe, John D." in the AT using VB Scripting without going individually going through each line?  I am using ArcGIS 9.3.

I should note that not all the names are the same; they are different.  Is it possible to select those in the column with different names and just reverse the "first, last name" to "last name, first"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be using the field calculator. It does go through every line, but I'm not sure I understand how you would do this without iterating through the table in some manner. I am not good at VB Script, but you can use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function to separate based on the first space in the string (assuming all names follow that structure), and it should be something like this:

EDIT: Apologies to the opening poster, I actually got it all wrong. Here is my best attempt at a VB script that will put the last word in a space-delimited string at the beginning with a comma and then add the rest, but I am getting a syntax error. If you can find it, please edit this to be correct! I will continue to poke at it until then.

```
Function switchpos(ByVal theString As String) As String
    Dim theArray() As String
    Dim theFinal as String
    theArray() = Split(theString, " ", -1)
    For i = LBound(theArray) To UBound(theArray)-1
        theFinal = theFinal & theArray(i)
    Next
    switchpos = theArray(UBound(theArray)) & ", " & theFinal
    Return switchpos
End Function
```

I'm still working on a good method to get the rest of the variable strings added up. If you want a quick stopgap in python, plug the following into your Codeblock:

```
def nameswitch(theString):
names = theString.Split()
b = ""
for name in names:
    if(name == names[-1]):
        continue
    b = b+name+" "
return names[-1]+", "+b
```

And put this in the execution block:

```
namswitch([FIELD])
```

The previous code took the Table value `STOCK LN FREEDOM` and returned `FREEDOM, STOCK LN`.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Two problems with this: first, the string will only be split at the first occurrence of the delimiter (i.e. "John D. Doe" would be split into "John" and "D. Doe"), which is not helpful in Zoran's case; second, you're not changing the order of the string components, but simply inserting a comma after the first component.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I completely misread that, somehow. Let me fix that.

Comment: i got it now,  Split( [ADDR_SN]," ",2)(0) & ", " & Split( [ADDR_SN], " ",2)(1)  -

I changed the (0) to (1) -- (1) to (0)

Comment: What I gave you before doesn't switch the names around. I'm working on a VB solution, but there's a python one up for now.

Comment: Ok, I have another question....  what about the the middle name/Initial?  I played around with the numbers to make the adjustment, but that did not work... suggestions?

Comment: I added a VB script that you should be able to use in your codeblock, but something it is incomplete, but I'm a pythoner, not a VB-er, so I'm having a heck of a time debugging the error. The logic should be correct, but I will continue to work on it.

Comment: This is basically the right idea.  However, breaking the name into lots of little pieces is inefficient and can destroy information.  The core loop can be implemented by (a) extracting the final token as in `lastName = theArray(UBound(theArray))` and (b) deleting that token from the end of the original string and concatenating it with what remains, separated by a comma, as in `switchpos = lastName & ", " & Replace(theString & "!", lastName & "!", "")`  The exclamation point is a sentinel; the procedure works best when the sentinel is known not to appear in the string at all.

Comment: I considered using replace, but it didn't seem to want to work out correctly for me, either. VB is not my specialty when it comes to the Field Calc, but I gave it my best shot. How might information be lost in splitting, though?

Comment: Information can be lost when sequences of delimiters are replaced by single delimiters (or, as in your current version, no delimiters at all!). Normally this isn't a big deal--compressing multiple spaces to single spaces could be part of a data-cleaning process--but in other circumstances, sequences of multiple delimiters can be meaningful. Also, the `replace` approach generalizes to a more powerful solution: start by replacing all possible delimiters, including ".", by a space; extract the final token, then delete that token *at the end of the original string* and proceed as before.

Comment: Sometimes you're so logical it hurts.

Comment: May you live long and prosper.

Comment: One last question-- how can you be sure that the string you are replacing/removing only appears once in the target string, and that, if you remove it, you only remove the one at the end?

Answer (score 3):

If you're fortnuate enough that every single name is in the format "First M. Last", you'll be able to use ". " as the delimeter, and use the following expression in the Field Calculator:

```
Split( [NAME],". ")(1) & ", " & Split( [NAME], ". ")(0) & "."
```

However, if the names are not all in that same format, you will need a more complex method like Nathanus's revised one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I might have missed something but I tried to account for the "Middle" section.

Codeblock pre logic:

```
def swapNames(name):
    nameList = name.split()
    first = nameList[0]
    middle = nameList[1:-1]
    last = nameList[-1]
    z = ""
    for n in middle:
        z += n + " "

    return str(last) + ", " + str(first) + " " + str(z)
```

Bottom section

swapNames( !nameTest!)